# Jquery Change Image on selections on ajax html changes

Tags: jquery, dom, refresh, selection

I am trying to change product images when different colors are selected. My jQuery code works fine when I use straight HTML but when I try to change the images with the selections made with Ajax only the first selection works. It seems that my jQuery only reads the initial html and not the changes made after the initial load. I thought that `.on` would handle the updated html but I seem to be missing something. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  var data = {
   "1" : { img: "/test.png" },
   "2" : { img: "/test_1.png" },
   "3" : { img: "/test_2.png" },
  };
   jQuery('[name*="Color"]').on('change',function() {
var value = jQuery(this).val();
if (data[value] != undefined)
{
    jQuery('#product-image').attr('src', data[value].img);        
}
 });});
```

Comment: `jQuery(this).find().val();` _find_ what?

Comment: The value of the option <select name="Color"><option value="this value"></option></select>

Comment: `find()` finds an element in the context of the selected element, in this case there is no need for using it, you should remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Brandon Aaron's livequery plugin to accomplish what I was trying to do. I was under the impression that the livequery plugin only worked with older versions of jQuery turns out I was wrong it works great with 1.7.1 Still not sure why `.on` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo your event binding after the insertion of the new nodes to your document. Try to insert the code:

```
jQuery('[name*="Color"]').on('change',function()...
```

In the load function callback.

**Edit:**

I realize now that you registered a load event in the window document... You are doing wrong... You need to load the new nodes, insert them and register their events.

You need to do something like:

```
$( "#idOfTheElementThatWillContainTheNewNodes" ).load(
    "url to obtain the code to be inserted",
    { param1: value1, ..., paramN : valueN }, // parameters to be sent to the server (if any)
    function( responseText, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest ) {    // this is the load callback. it will run after the request is complete
        // ok, the responseText was inserted in "idOfTheElementThatWillContainTheNewNodes" container.
        // now you do register your events...
    }
);
```

Take a look in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

I created an example for you, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/zuFsc/

Comment: I appreciate the help and the education.